# Can't upload images on new theme

Tags: theme-development, images, themes, uploads

I am using underscores to create a new WordPress theme, the site is being hosted locally using MAMP. Whenever I try and upload a image either in a post or in the theme customization tab, this error is shown "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

I have tried reinstalling WordPress but the issue prevails. Also if the theme is changed images upload perfectly.

Anyone know what might cause this, is there something missing in the underscores code that is creating this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a common Mac OSX issue – you need to adjust your file permission for the uploads folder. The problem with changing the permissions manually is your have to change them each time you create a new project, which is tiring.

You can give MAMP permission and you will never have to worry about the same problem again. Here are some instructions: http://ifmeister.com/mamp-file-permissions-for-a-local-development-environment/

Good luck.